# Overlay/fade image over beginning of MKV with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, fade, video-editing, mkv

I've got an MKV that I would like to replace the first 5 seconds with a static png image that fades in/out from black. How can I accomplish this with just ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy method is to overlay the image:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -loop 1 -t 5 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1]fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=4[fg];[0]drawbox=t=fill:enable='lte(t,5)'[bg];[bg][fg]overlay=eof_action=pass:x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- I added the drawbox filter to make a black background because I didn't know the size of your image.
- See [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).